# Unexpected NameError: uninitialized constant, when using factory_bot

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, factory-bot, minitest

Here is the test file:

```
require 'test_helper'
require_relative './factories/stock'

module CoreDomainTest
  class PortfolioTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
    include FactoryBot::Syntax::Methods

    def test_portfolio_model_creation
      positions = build_list(:stock, 5)
    end
  end
end
```

Here is factory file:

```
require 'factory_bot'
require 'faker'

FactoryBot.define do
  factory :stock do
    ticker { Faker::Finance.ticker }
    name { Faker::Company.name }
    sector { Faker::Company.industry }
    cusip { nil }
    isin { nil }
    sedol { nil }
    price { Faker::Commerce.price(range: 0..10_000) }
  end
end
```

then when I executed `rails test test/domain/test_portfolio`, get this error:

```
Error:
CoreDomainTest::PortfolioTest#test_portfolio_model_creation:
NameError: uninitialized constant Stock
    test/domain/test_portfolio.rb:9:in `test_portfolio_model_creation'
```

I can't understand the origin of this error.  Please provide some thought or ideas?

Comment: Do you have a Stock class defined in `app/models/stock.rb`?

Comment: The error is because you are asking FactoryBot to build a Stock object but the Stock class is not defined

Comment: @OlexiyKutsenko : BTW, `factory` accepts an optional parameter `class: CLASSNAME`, where you can explicitly specify the class to be constructed, if the defaults don't apply. I personally prefer to always provide the class explicitly, because I find it easier to understand.

Comment: @user1934428, what if I need a plain ruby object from the factory - nothing else?

Comment: @blowmage, what if I need a plain ruby object from the factory - nothing else?

Comment: @engineersmnky, what if I need a plain ruby object from the factory - nothing else?

Comment: You still need a Class that defines this Object. Factory Bot cannot just mock an Object out of thin air. This does not necessarily need to be an AR object but the class definition absolutely has to exist.

Comment: @engineersmnky, thanks

Comment: What is a **plain** Ruby object? What objects would not be plain?